# To display an image and some text on the selection of an item in a list

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I am trying to make a product search feature for a program of mine.
It's primary function is to retrieve a list of products from a database(100+) and then add them all to a list. I want the user to be able to select an item from a list and relevant product information to appear in a Text Area and and an image in jLabel next to it. Is there a way to do this without a long if statement.

Is it possible to assign a value to each product in the SQL table and have a folder with the images named according to the product's assigned number.
For example:

```
Product:           Assigned Value:          Image Name:
x                  1                           p1.jpg
y                  2                           p2.jpg  
z                  3                           p3.jpg
```

And then have a code like setImageIcon((//FolderPath)/p"int retrieved from SQL table".jpg);
Also is there a similar method to add the product description to the Text Area?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are the images not in the DB?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output, space delimited tables & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: I did not know that it was possible to add images to a MySQL database. Could you tell me how to go about this. I am confident I could do the rest myself if that could be achieved. But I have heard that this only works well for low resolution images and is generally not recommended. Most of my images are high-resolution.

Comment: The data type of files in database are BLOB.